# Write webpage text in <code> or <pre> while keeping < and > tags in the text - (ie. "<mycustomtag>")

Tags: html, css, syntax, formatting, pre

I have this C++ code (see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfx2v70a/)):

```
#include <ossource>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World! \n";

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to include that in a code section on my webpage with the indents etc intact, however when I place it in `<pre>` tag (or similar) it doesn't like the `<ossource>` part because it believes the angled brackets `<` and `>` are html, not raw text. So it removes them (see jsfiddle above).

Is there an easy way to display this code exactly as it is?

I have tried using `<code>` and `<pre>` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### use HTML entities for `<` and `>` characters

To render language-reserved characters like `<`, `>`, or `\`, it's common to escape the symbol, so that it won't be interpreted as part of language syntax.

You could use `&lt;` or `&#60;` for `<` sign, and `&gt;` or `&#62;` for `>` sign in HTML.

See the sample snippet below.

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    #include &lt;ossource&gt;

    int main()
    {
      std::cout << "Hello World! \n";

      return 0;
    }
  </code>
</pre>

<hr />

<pre>
  <code>
    #include &#60;ossource&#62;

    int main()
      {
        std::cout << "Hello World! \n";

        return 0;
      }
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: It is usually enough to replace all `<` with `&lt;`: No `<` results in no valid tags, so escaping `>` becomes redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, your content should be inside `<code>` within `<pre>`, since it is pre-formatted code.

This requires you to escape the reserved characters by using their respective HTML entities, as [Bumhan Yu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75797534/13561410) shows.

---

In case you do not want to properly escape the content and do not want to use semantically correct elements, you can use `<textarea>`.

The `<textarea>` element only accepts text as its content, so any sequence except its own closing tag `</textarea>` is allowed.

Since `<textarea>` contains *plain-text content*, we should label its content type appropriately, by e.g. associating a `<label>` element, or using the `aria-label` attribute:

```html
<p><label for="c-snippet">C code:</label></p>

<textarea id="c-snippet" readonly rows=8 cols=33>#include <ossource>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World! \n";

    return 0;
}</textarea>
```

**Note**: You may want to set the [`readonly` boolean attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#readonly) to disallow editing. You can use the `cols` and `rows` attributes to set the width and height in characters, respectively.